# Appimage problems

Tags: ruby, linux, appimage

I would like to release my program that wrote in ruby language, I need to pack ruby to appimage file and send it to my client ubuntu PC first.

so I create the folder "ruby-img", then copy my compiled ruby which in "/app/ruby" folder to "ruby-img/app/ruby" and then made a link as "ln -r -s app/ruby/bin/ruby usr/bin/." in "ruby-img" folder.

then I create the desktop file and put png file to "ruby-img", using appimagetool to create ruby-x86_64.AppImage. sadly it can not run, AFAIK that ruby.AppImage still using /app/ruby/lib folder to find some library of ruby but not in "ruby-img/app/ruby/lib" related folder.

so I tried re-compile ruby as --prefix=/tmp/ruby or --prefix=/usr/local/ruby, then copy them to "ruby-img/usr/local/ruby" or "ruby-img/tmp/ruby" then maka some link as above, and repack to AppImage but ruby.AppImage still not working...

any idea can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

AppImages contain of a filesystem with all the content you provide plus a small executable stub that will mount the AppImage filesystem, then run the AppRun executable to be found inside.

With that knowledge it is utmost important that you provide an executable in the root directory along with the .desktop and icon files. I suggest you do not create AppRun yourself. Use the precompiled one from https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases/tag/continuous (do not forget to rename it to exactly 'AppRun').

Now when this AppRun gets invoked, it will perform a few checks, cd into the /usr directory and try to start the executable specified in the .desktop file. Check it's [source code](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/blob/master/src/AppRun.c) and you can see that it also sets a few environment variables.

Therefore it is best you provide your entrypoint as /usr/bin/ruby.sh and register that in the desktop file. Remember if /usr/bin/ruby.sh gets called, the current work directory is /usr. So ruby.sh can set further environment variables such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that the libraries you configured for /usr/lib will actually be loaded.

With that I hope you have at least as much success as I had.